# Permission denied using svn to commit files into wordpress repository

Tags: wordpress, svn, repository

I've a problem to commit files into my wordpress repository.
Some information:

I created / downloaded the files to my local machine as an administrator.
When I was administrator on my local machine I could commit my files.
Everythings works fine.

some days ago I lost my rights on my local machine (business computer) and I'm not administrator.

[image]

Now I can't commit files.
I got the error message 'permission denied' / 'Access to /dmd-pages forbidden'.

So my question is.
Must I open some ports? 
Can I only commit files as an administrator?

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a issue in my firewall.

The ports of the git program were blocked.